# how to overwrite initialization of standard method

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

can we use standard 'InsertCpDialog$initialize()' in our javascript like this , so that i can call other function once it get initializes. I used like below code but it is not working. :(

```
Type.registerNamespace("Extensions");
Extensions.InsertCpDialog.prototype.initialize  = function InsertCpDialog$initialize()
{
alert('hi  inside insert');
var p = this.properties;
if(window.document.nameProp == "Name" || window.document.title == "Name") {

    var browserName=navigator.appName; // Get the Browser Name

    if(browserName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer") // For IE
    {
    alert('hi inside IE');
//window.onload=init(); // Call init function in IE
    }
    else
    {
    if (document.addEventListener) // For Firefox
    {
    alert('hi inside firefox');    
//document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init(), false); // Call init function in Firefox
    }
}
}
}
```

Original(standard) one is like:

```
Type.registerNamespace ("Tridion.Cme.Views");  
Tridion.Cme.Views.InsertCpDialog = function InsertCpDialog()
{
Type.enableInterface(this, "Tridion.Cme.Views.InsertCpDialog");
this.addInterface("Tridion.Cme.Views.DashboardBase");
};

Tridion.Cme.Views.InsertCpDialog.prototype.initialize = function InsertCpDialog$initialize()
{
}
```

**Edit**

hi frank thank you, but already i am using same thing in my code to get the list of componet and template listed on a page under CP tab.

```
function getbtn() {
//alert('inside getbtn');
var sbtn = document.getElementById ("buttonComponentInsert");
$evt.addEventHandler(sbtn , "click", getListofCPBtnClick);
} 

function getListofCPBtnClick(e) {
//code will go here    
}
```

**My question is :** 
I need to get selected Component and template Id from **Insert CP window**.Earlier i was able to get that by changing the CME extension standard code, but i am not suppose to do that, So first i am trying to initialize the "insert CP window" from my javascript code. I can create event handler for that window, but my question is how to initialize that so that i can call any function once it get initialize. Kindly let me know if i anot clear.

Comment: In the post Frank mentions, Albert provides the callback to run any code you'd need to after a view finishes loading and in the blog comments, Boris Ponomarenko explains how to extend specific views to improve performance along with sample configuration. Is that enough to initialize your code and create event listeners?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your script getting loaded into the dialog?

If not, Albert shows how to do that here: http://albertromkes.com/2012/01/30/tridion-gui-extensions-how-to-load-a-javascript-without-showing-a-gui-element/

He then also shows how to listen to events to accomplish something similar to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks frank, already i am using these code to create a event handler,kindly help me to initialize the Popup window, so that i can use my codes to get control inside that popup window.